# Is it possible to click on a Javascript pop-up window with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?

Tags: perl, firefox, download, mechanize

I'll try to make myself as clear as possible. I want to download automatically a file.
What I've done so far:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use Crypt::SSLeay;
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;
$url = $url.@ARGV[0]; 
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new;
$mech->get( $url );
$mech->form_name('sysinfo');
$mech->click_button( name => 'download' );
```

When I click that button a window pops up, because of an **onclick()** js event. It asks what I want to do with the file, so I need to click the **Save** button. The thing is I can't get the window to do it. I can't use **get** because the only URL I know is the one that pops the new window up. 
I've couldn't find something similar. So is it possible to do what I want? or is there other way?
I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is function on onclick()? Maybe you can try paste this in url bar `javascript:function_on_onclick(param1, param2);`

If it will be works, try `$mech->get('javascript:function_on_onclick(param1, param2);');`